# Excluding all files that begin with X in .htaccess maintenance mode redirect

Tags: .htaccess, maintenance

Here's my maintenance mode redirect:

```
# MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^0\.0\.0\.0
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ads/.*$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ad_([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.php$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/.*$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/new/$ [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /new/ [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm trying to exclude all files that begin with "ad_" from the redirect. I'm trying that with this line:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ad_([0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.php$ [NC]`

Unfortunately, there are hundreds of these files in the public root folder, not in their own subfolder. Examples of these files:

- ad_login.php
- ad_message_editor.php
- ad_manage_mm_account_1.php

These file names include anywhere from 1-4 underscores, but they all have at least one, starting with "ad_".

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `_` to your regexp, like 
 `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ad_([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)\.php$ [NC]`

UPD Edit:
And as @MrWhite mentioned in comment - add slash prefix as you have in other rules.

Comment: They are also missing the slash prefix on the URL-path (as shown in the other conditions).

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's true @MrWhite !